# WPF Window resizing in a different direction

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, resize, window

I am having trouble making my WPF window resize in a different direction. Currently, when I shoot an event in my application, application resizes down (I make an element visible and then WPF window automatically resizes). I would like that my application would instead resize up, so that the application would not become hidden by a taskbar. How does one do that?

Below is a picture explaining my problem. Picture 1 shows small window. Picture 2 shows the problem, where window resizes beyond the screen. Picture 3 shows what I want to do.

I can surely code this resizing in my code, where I would move the window, but is there not a nice way in WPF?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `Width` or `Height` property of your window will always change the layout of it to the *right* or *bottom*.

The `Left` and `Top` property of the window determine the X- and Y-Offset of your window relative to the top-left corner of your screen.

To achieve your goal, you have to do 2 steps:

- Increase the window `Height` by the amount of **X**
- Decrease the window `Top` by the amount of **X**

Comment: I use Sticky Windows (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6045/Sticky-Windows-How-to-make-your-top-level-forms-to) and unfortunately it doesnt work anymore if I change the size of the window. Any way to solve this problem?